# HTTP:Post or Get Request for GeoLocation

Tags: post, get

On my website, a person types in their Zipcode on the homepage, which give me Long and Lat values of the zip code.

The user get's redirected to another **/search/** page.

Currently, I have a `<form>` which posts the lat and long values and I use them to render the page in the backend.

Alternatively, I could set up the same this using search parameters. Instead of **/search/**  and using `<form>`, I can use a GET request, by including the Lat and Long as a URL parameter as follows: **/search?lat=xxx&long=xxx/** . Then I can pass a GET request on the search page instead of a previous POST.

In the second case, I think Google Crawler is likely to index more pages? And possible give me better rankings?

Which one is the correct way to go?

Comment: What about $_SESSION or cookie ?

Comment: @Nubian sorry, I'm fairly new to this, I generally just store the user id the $_SESSION so that I know who the user is. I failed to see how I could use it for geolocation, and why it's the better choice. Same for cookie

Comment: $_SESSION['userid'] = 1;
$_SESSION['lat'] = "xxx";
$_SESSION['long'] = "xxx";

Then you can pass $_SESSION[lat] and $_SESSION[long] to your code. That will help you not using GET o POST methods of retrieving lat and long.

Or, am I missing something?

Comment: It definitely has to be GET, because POST data cannot be preserved in this manner, so your content wont be indexed at all if you use post.